# printf char* pointer which points to long and float

Tags: c, printf, long-integer

I am doing some exercises from book "Understanding pointers in C". The book gives you a piece of code and asks you for what you get in output.

One of them is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c, *cc;
    int i;
    long l;
    float f;

    c = 'Z';
    i = 15;
    l = 77777;
    f = 3.14;
    cc = &c;
    printf("c=%c cc=%u\n", *cc, cc);
    cc = &i;
    printf("i=%d cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
    cc=&l;
    printf("l=%ld cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
    cc=&f;
    printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
c=Z cc=1946293623
i=15 cc=1946293616
l=4294967249 cc=1946293608
f=0.000000 cc=4294967235
```

I don't understand **why** `l` and `f` are not printed as `77777` and `3.14`?

I checked the book The C programming language to see if the if the `printf`'s control chars are correct, and they are.

Comment: @SheerFish: Why tell us just his initials? His name is Yashavant Kanetkar. I haven't read any of his books, so I can't judge them, but if this program is a typical sample I agree that they should be avoided -- *unless* the text makes it clear that the program is not an example of valid C. (This was a response to a now-deleted comment recommending avoiding the author of "Understanding Pointers in C", whose initials are YK.)

Comment: @MM.: "blame `varargs`? What does that mean? `varargs` is a very old mechanism, replaced by `<stdarg.h>`. The problem with the code in the question is blatant misuse of pointers and `printf`.

Comment: LOL maybe I fell aslee: I did not notice that YK pretends to use a char * for printing integers, floats, etc. Is he crazy?

Comment: I think the author wants you to find errors, since I have done another exercize and the code is wrong

Comment: Massively incorrect code could indicate either an exercise to find the errors, or incompetence on the part of the author. I'd need to see the surrounding text of the book to be able to tell the difference. (For example, Schildt's use of `void main()` in many of his C books indicates incompetence and/or ignorance on his part; the text of his books shows no indication that he knows it's wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
printf("l=%ld cc=%u\n",*(long*)cc,cc);
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*(float*)cc,cc);
```

Comment: cool, it worked. When 10 minutes will pass away, I will be able to check your answer as accepted.
One question: why is it necessary to cast the pointers?

Comment: @Caterpillar Size to which the pointer is pointing is because different.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: It's not just a matter of size; the *types* have to match. And that kind of pointer cast trickery can have undefined behavior; if `cc` (a `char*`) happens to point to an address that isn't aligned correctly for a `long` or `float` object, the program can crash (on some systems).

Comment: @KeithThompson Printf will determine on the operator, such as of "% ld" if there is size address is match. see va_arg.

Comment: I acknowledge that in itself to use the char pointer for such purpose is system dependent. I should probably use a void pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Different arguments of the same size and different types can be passed as arguments in different ways. If the type of an argument doesn't match the type specified by the format string, the behavior is undefined. Size matters not.

Comment: e.g if sizeof(double) and sizeof(long) (and address is correct)then `printf("l=%ld cc=%p\n",*(double*)v,v);` (It seems) to act as expected.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: What do you mean by "it is made to match"? If it doesn't match, it doesn't match, and the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior covers anything from crashing your program to *appearing* to behave as expected (whatever your expectations happen to be). In `printf("l=%ld cc=%p\n",*(double*)v,v);`, you're passing a `double` argument for a `"%ld"` format; the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson I use the Google translation I is not a native. It seems difficult but also is said to explain in more detail there is a discrepancy in my English if. Sorry.

Comment: `*(double*)` memory images are stacked in fact is `long`. (It is that different from the intent of the programmer). Remember va_arg.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I don't think this is just an English language problem. You *cannot* assume that `double` and `long` objects are stored the same way; even if they happen to have the same size, they can have different alignments, and they can be passed differently as arguments to `printf`. Code that treats the same object as both `double` and `long` is dangerously non-portable (and almost certainly unnecessary).

Comment: @KeithThompson It seems like the most that you at all. But would not have little real that such alignment that is different? It seems to be a thing that you can not also like to analyze the type of another double with a `union` if so.

Comment: I think in addition to the kind of story, my reply is accept but your answer is appropriate.

Comment: "It seems like the most that you at all." -- I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by that. Yes, it's likely that if `long` and `double` happen to have the same size (they often don't), then they *probably* have the same alignment. But it's not guaranteed, and it's a bad idea (and unnecessary) to make that kind of assumption.

Comment: @KeithThompson I found well. and i'm sorry English is funny.

Answer (score 3):

As Bryan's answer says, the types of the arguments passed to `printf` need to match the types specified by the format string.

The format to print a pointer value is `"%p"` -- and it expects a `void*` argument; a pointer of another type should be explicitly cast to `void*`.

Your program has undefined behavior because of the type mismatches. It also has constraint violations because it attempts to assign incompatible pointer types without a cast; `cc = &i;` is illegal (but a compiler can merely warn about it if it chooses). You *should* have gotten several warnings from your compiler.

I *hope* the intent of that program is to demonstrate what *not* to do. Let's consider just the last two lines before the `return` statement:

```
cc=&f;
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
```

`cc = &f;` violates a constraint and requires a diagnostic (IMHO a good compiler *should* give you a fatal error and reject the program). `&f` is of type `float*`, and `cc` is of type `char*`; those types are not assignment-compatible.

Most compilers that accept that statement assume it implies an implicit conversion, making it equivalent to the legal but tricky:

```
cc = (char*)&f;
```

This causes `cc` to point to the first byte of the `float` object `f`.

```
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
```

This claims to print the value of `f`, but it doesn't; it prints the value of the `char` object that `cc` points to, which happens to be the first byte of `f`. And it uses a `%f` format for that `char` object, which has undefined behavior. The result is garbage.

I was going to write a "corrected" version of that program, but it has so many problems, I couldn't figure out just what it's intended to do.

> I checked the book The C programming language to see if the if the printf's control chars are correct, and they are.

No, they aren't. `"%f"` is correct for printing a `float` or `double` argument (`float` is promoted to `double` in this context), but you're passing a `char` argument.

This would be correct:

```
printf("*cc = %d, cc = %p\n", *cc, (void*)cc);
```

but it doesn't do the same thing; it prints the char pointed to by `cc` as an `int` (you could use `%c` to print it as a character, but it's likely to be unprintable), and then prints the value of `cc` as a pointer.

It would be interesting to see what the book says about this program.

Comment: Mr.Thompson,since you've already taken the trouble to write such an elegant answer, can you spare a minute to kindly write the correct version of the code for the following -- `How to print the values of the long & float variables using the char* once their addresses have been assigned to the char* after casting?`.Are `printf("l=%ld cc=%p\n",*(long*)cc,cc);` and `printf("f=%f cc=%p\n",*(float*)cc,cc);` totally wrong?

Comment: What I mean is, does `*(float*)cc` tell the program to interpret `sizeof(float)` number of bytes as a float for the %f format specifier,as otherwise `*cc` will consider only a single byte for interpretation for float,as `cc` is a char*?

Comment: @SheerFish: If `cc` hold the result of a conversion of a valid `float*` value, then converting it back from `char*` to `float*` will almost certainly give you the original pointer value. Actually `void*` is a better "generic" pointer type, but for historical reasons `char*` and `void*` are required to have the same representation. But most of the time, if you want a pointer to a `float`, just use a `float*` and *no casts*. If you really need something that can point to either a `long` or a `float`, there are ways to do it -- but learn ordinary pointer operations first.

Comment: So you mean if `ptr` is a `char*`,and `pi` is a float variable,then at the end of the following sequence of statements we get float `pi` back? Here :  `ptr=(char*)&pi;` followed by `*(float*)ptr;`That's all!!Please confirm it.It will clarify a lot of things for me.As far as I see it goes by what you said in the above comment,ie, `ptr` holds a valid `float*` value, and then is dereferenced after casting that pointer back to `float*`.

Comment: @SheerFish: It's guaranteed if you use `void*` rather than `char*`. I *think* it's also guaranteed if you use `char*`. (But just use `float*` to point to `float` objects unless there's a *specific* reason that you need a "generic" pointer.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me.Yes, I see no reason using anything other than float* to point to a float.I was only speaking in the context of this question.And if you `think` it is so about `char*`, I have little reason not to believe it's `guaranteed` to be so!!

Comment: @SheerFish: There are valid reasons to use "generic" pointers. If a given piece of data can be *either* floating-point *or* integral, and can't ever be both, it can make sense to store both in the same memory location -- as long as you keep track of what's stored there.

Comment: I listen to all you say, though I must admit it will take me some time to assimilate it all completely.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The format specifiers of `printf` (and worse so `scanf`) have to match the types passed as parameters. If you are using `gcc` then use the `-Wall` option and it will also give warnings about this. Your code should look like this:

```
printf("c=%c cc=%u\n", *cc, (unsigned int)cc);
cc = &i;
```

Taking the address of `i` into a `char*` interpretation doesn't make sense anymore and neither does it for the others below. By assigning pointers you enforce a wrong interpretation of the same bit representation.

Comment: By assigning an `int*` value to a `char*` object, you violate a constraint, which means a conforming compiler *must* issue a diagnostic and (IMHO) *should* reject the program. It's not at all clear that `cc = &i;` implies a conversion even if it's accepted. The conversion can be done with a cast: `cc = (char*)&i;`.

Comment: Even though aesthetics (maybe even ethics ;) is totally on your side, I'm afraid in C most implicit (or explicit) pointer conversions are acceptable. In Embedded-C with memory spaces things get a bit different. Casting to a `char*` (implicit or explicit) even has special status as being more legal than any other pointer.

Comment: Explicit pointer conversions are one thing if you know what're doing. They're inherently non-portable in most cases -- but one of the great strengths of C is the ability to write non-portable code. Supposedly implicit conversions, as in `cc = &i;`, are another matter. Such conversions are explicitly prohibited by the language standard, in terms just as strong as those that forbid syntax errors. Many compilers will let you get away with it -- but adding the required cast: `cc = (char*)&i;` is easy to do, completely addresses the legality issue, and visibly emphasizes the non-portability.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("l=%ld cc=%u\n",*(long*)cc,cc);
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*(float*)cc,cc);
```

this works but

```
printf("l=%ld cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
```

this does not  as expecte becuase of following reasons.

Every pointer is of 4 bytes (depends on OS not on where it is pointing.)
so even a address of float can be stored into char * .
bu when we do pointer arithmetics or when we read the value of pointer `*cc` it reads numer of characters based on type of pointer...

Suppose a character is of 2 bytes then `*cc` will read only 2 bytes with address in `cc` where as the float or long number has been  stored in 4 bytes (or more). 
so it will show invalid data.

when we typecast it `*(long*)cc` then its teated as long pointer with explicit typecasting.

Answer (score 1):

> So many things that are wrong with your program!!!

First things first, don't use the `%u` format specifier for pointers.`unsigned integers` and `pointers` needn't essentially have the same size.Always use `%p` for `pointers`.Eg

```
printf("c=%c cc=%p\n", *cc, cc);
```

Second most important thing--**NEVER** use that book "Understanding pointers in C" by YK (I can't name the author in full due to obvious reasons).His other book is notorious as the "void main" book here on SO.

Third,coming back to your program, I am surprised you didn't get any warnings while you assign addresses of integer and float variables to a character pointer, **without a cast.**.This is bound to produce errors as your program won't be able to know how many bytes to interpret from the pointed location. `int`,`float`,and `char` vary in sizes.And you may wonder why you didn't get error for `int` then? Right? It's because of the little endian architecture of your computer, whereby the least significant bytes are stored first.

So here's your correction:

```
cc =(char*) &i;
printf("i=%d cc=%p\n",*(int*)cc,cc);
cc=(char*)&l;
printf("l=%ld cc=%p\n",*(long*)cc,cc);
cc=(char*)&f;
printf("f=%f cc=%p\n",*(float*)cc,cc);
```

Comment: oh lol, it is true, YK pretends to use a char * for printing integers, floats, etc. Is he crazy? I am starting understanding why you told me TO NOT use this book. Could you please tell me more about this book in a private message if it is possible? Thank you very much

Comment: @Caterpillar Unfortunately private messaging is not possible in StackOverflow.If you need further clarification, post it as a comment just like this.

Comment: @Caterpillar And the worst thing about that book--`It's plagiarized` from a 1992 international book, and too much non-standard and compiler dependent rubbish is inserted into that book to make it sound original.

Comment: The reason you can't mention **Yashavant Kanetkar**'s name is far from obvious to me; it took me just a moment to [find it](http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Pointers-C-Yashavant-Kanetkar/dp/8176563587/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1366645281&sr=1-3).

Comment: @KeithThompson I had assumed one can't promote anyone on this forum or utter unflattering things about him as well, even if that's the truth!!

Comment: @Sheer Fish ok, could you please suggest me the name of the international book of 1992 you mentioned? It will be so useful to me. Thank you very much

Comment: [Understanding Pointers in C](http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Pointers-C-Yashavant-Kanetkar/dp/8176563587/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1366645281&sr=1-3), by Yashavant Kanetkar. I haven't read it myself, but if the code in the question is typical, I strongly recommend against using the book -- unless the text makes it *very* clear that the code is not an example of valid C.

Comment: @Caterpillar Here's the link to that book by `Mike Banahan,Declan Brady and Mark Doran`, published in 1991.It's simply called `The C book`.It's so elegantly written, and so brazenly plagiarized by YK, that you will curse the plagiarist each time you read this elegant book.  http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/

Comment: @SheerFish: I'm aware of no such rule. Try searching on stackoverflow (or elsewhere) for the name Schildt, another author notorious for recommmending `void main()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Mr.Thompson, First Amendment and Freedom of Speech is something distinctly American,even today,despite the Europeans claiming they too are part of the Free World.In most part of the world,it doesn't take much to drag a citizen to the court even if he speaks factually.

Comment: @KeithThompson I heard Schildt and YK are wildly popular for the same reason --Their `friendly` and `accessible` style.For YK,I've no grouse,except that he should give credit to the original authors.A few errors can be ignored, but outright plagiarism can't.

Comment: Concerning errors in code: I think the author wants you to find errors, since I have done another exercize and the code is so uncorrect

Comment: @Caterpillar See if we can talk over gtalk.I feel odd busting a fellow in a public forum,even though what I stated are facts that can be attested by any programmer worth his salt.It's like that pony-tailed fellow in a major South Asian nation who peddles fake MBA degrees not recognized by any reliable authority and claims those degrees are certified in Belgium (Word goes he has pocketed millions from this scam and has politicians and judges in his pocket.He even pressurized IBM's subsidiary there to fire an employee who factually pointed out this scam in his blog)

Comment: @Sheer Fish you can contact me at the e-mail you can find in this image https://www.wuala.com/Caterpillar/Documenti/canc/img/?key=q96pNXtyVuHA